# Refactoring sample code into class raises no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I an new on CPP and try to "refactor" this example code https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WPS/WPS.ino into a class called 
ApiClient`. I then wanna be able to do something like this:

```
apiClient = ApiClient(myUrl);
apiClient.sendValue(key, value);
```

Everything compiles, except the `wifi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);` function call.
When I copy paste the whole example code in my `main.cpp` file the example is working. When I use my "refactored" approach, the `wifi.onEvent(WifiEvent)` is complaining.

**The exact error message:**

`no instance of overloaded function "WiFiClass::onEvent" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void (system_event_id_t event, system_event_info_t info)) -- object type is: WiFiClass`

**I know that the `onEvent` function normally takes two arguments, but why is this working in the example code? And how can I solve that?**

This is what I have so far:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "WiFi.h"
#include <esp_wps.h>
#include <Hythe22.h>
#include <ApiClient.h>

#define DHTPIN 14
// ?accessKey=ist_NJu3tjPIBCYeJd6DGGBxzq14LvungHoK&bucketKey=B37GHBNK5HL3
#define API_URL "https://groker.init.st/api/events";

Hythe22 dht(DHTPIN);
ApiClient apiClient;
uint64_t chipid;
#define ESP_DEVICE_NAME String(chipid)


void setup()
{
  String apiUrl = "https://myApi.Endpoint.com/event";
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println();
}

void loop()
{

  String temp = String(dht.temperature);
  Serial.println("TEMP:" + temp);
  apiClient.sendValue("temperature", temp);

  String hum = String(dht.humidity);
  Serial.println("HUM:" + hum);
  apiClient.sendValue("humidity", hum);
}
```

**ApiClient.h**

```
/*
===========================================================
*/

#ifndef WebClient_h
#define WebClient_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "esp_wps.h"
#include <HTTPClient.h>

class ApiClient
{
  public:
    ApiClient(String apiUrl);
    void sendValue(String key, String value);
    void wpsInitConfig();
    void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info);
    String wpspin2string(uint8_t a[]);
    String requestUrl;
    String _apiUrl;
    int chipid;

  private:
};

#endif
```

**ApiClient.cpp**

```
/*
===========================================================
*/

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ApiClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_wps.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>

int chipid;

#define ESP_WPS_MODE WPS_TYPE_PBC
#define ESP_MANUFACTURER "ESPRESSIF"
#define ESP_MODEL_NUMBER "ESP32"
#define ESP_MODEL_NAME "ESPRESSIF IOT"
#define ESP_DEVICE_NAME "ESP STATION"

String _apiUrl;
HTTPClient http;
String requestUrl;
WiFiClass wifi;

static esp_wps_config_t config;

ApiClient::ApiClient(String apiUrl)
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(10);

    Serial.println();

    wifi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
    wifi.mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);

    Serial.println("Starting WPS");

    wpsInitConfig();
    esp_wifi_wps_enable(&config);
    esp_wifi_wps_start(0);
}

void sendValue(String key, String value)
{
    HTTPClient http;
    Serial.println("key:" + key);
    Serial.println("value:" + value);
    requestUrl = _apiUrl + "?" + key + "=" + value;
    // Serial.println(apiUrl);
    http.begin(requestUrl);

    int httpCode = http.GET();

    if (httpCode > 0)
    {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
        //file found at server --> on unsucessful connection code will be -1
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK)
        {
            String payload = http.getString();
            Serial.println(payload);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }
    http.end();
}

void ApiClient::wpsInitConfig()
{
    config.crypto_funcs = &g_wifi_default_wps_crypto_funcs;
    config.wps_type = ESP_WPS_MODE;
    strcpy(config.factory_info.manufacturer, ESP_MANUFACTURER);
    strcpy(config.factory_info.model_number, ESP_MODEL_NUMBER);
    strcpy(config.factory_info.model_name, ESP_MODEL_NAME);
    strcpy(config.factory_info.device_name, ESP_DEVICE_NAME);
}

String wpspin2string(uint8_t a[])
{
    char wps_pin[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        wps_pin[i] = a[i];
    }
    wps_pin[8] = '\0';
    return (String)wps_pin;
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info){
  switch(event){
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START:
      Serial.println("Station Mode Started");
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
      Serial.println("Connected to :" + String(WiFi.SSID()));
      Serial.print("Got IP: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.println("Disconnected from station, attempting reconnection");
      WiFi.reconnect();
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_WPS_ER_SUCCESS:
      Serial.println("WPS Successfull, stopping WPS and connecting to: " + String(WiFi.SSID()));
      esp_wifi_wps_disable();
      delay(10);
      WiFi.begin();
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_WPS_ER_FAILED:
      Serial.println("WPS Failed, retrying");
      esp_wifi_wps_disable();
      esp_wifi_wps_enable(&config);
      esp_wifi_wps_start(0);
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_WPS_ER_TIMEOUT:
      Serial.println("WPS Timedout, retrying");
      esp_wifi_wps_disable();
      esp_wifi_wps_enable(&config);
      esp_wifi_wps_start(0);
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_WPS_ER_PIN:
      Serial.println("WPS_PIN = " + wpspin2string(info.sta_er_pin.pin_code));
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe, you confused things. After having looked into the github link, I found out: `WiFiClass::onEvent()` is inherited from [`WiFiGenericClass`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.h) which provides three `onEvent()` methods. They all have two parameters but second might be left out as it has a default argument in each. However, these `onEvent()` methods are responsible to register a callback function (of three possible types). The registered function must match the resp. signature and you find the resp. types near the top of same header.

Comment: I am too new on C++. Can you please point an example how a function in my case can look like? Or should I keep that whole stuff in my main.cpp? (refactoring no good idea in that case?)

Comment: In C++, there is a difference between a free function and a member function. Your `void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info);` in `class ApiClient` is a member function. `WiFiClass` has no `onEvent()` which accepts a member function. I see two solutions: 1. Make `WiFiEvent` `static` and register `&ApiClass::WiFiEvent` but then you have no access to `this`. (I'm not sure wether I overlooked something but I couldn't see anything which what require `this` on a short glance.) 2. (IMHO better): bind instance of `ApiClass` with member function call using a lambda.

Comment: ... The second `WiFiClass::onEvent()` provides `std::function` which can bind nearly everything (with matching signature, of course) - including member function calls. To make "adaptering" easy, the lambda can be used: `wifi.onEvent([this](WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info) { this->WiFiEvent(event, info); });`.

Comment: @Scheff your approach 2 (Lambda) did the trick! If you post it as an answer, I would accept that. Thank you for that detailed (and in understandable, tight manner).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a look onto the [example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/examples/WPS/WPS.ino) linked in OP's question.

The relevant part is

```
void setup(){
  // contents skipped
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
  // contents skipped
}
```

Thereby `WiFiEvent` is a free function which is defined above:

```
void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info){
  switch(event){
    // some cases to handle various events
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

The OP wants to refactor this event handler into his `class ApiClient`:

```
class ApiClient
{
  public:
    ApiClient(String apiUrl);
    void sendValue(String key, String value);
    void wpsInitConfig();
    void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info);
    String wpspin2string(uint8_t a[]);
    String requestUrl;
    String _apiUrl;
    int chipid;

  private:
};
```

The essential difference is that `WiFiEvent()` becomes a member function due to this, and OP got the reported error

```
no instance of overloaded function "WiFiClass::onEvent" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (void (system_event_id_t event, system_event_info_t info)) -- object type is: WiFiClass
```

Out of curiosity, I digged a bit in the github project and finally found the declaration of `WiFiClass::onEvent()` – it's inherited from [`class WiFiGenericClass`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiGeneric.h):

```
class WiFiGenericClass
{
  public:
    WiFiGenericClass();

    wifi_event_id_t onEvent(WiFiEventCb cbEvent, system_event_id_t event = SYSTEM_EVENT_MAX);
    wifi_event_id_t onEvent(WiFiEventFuncCb cbEvent, system_event_id_t event = SYSTEM_EVENT_MAX);
    wifi_event_id_t onEvent(WiFiEventSysCb cbEvent, system_event_id_t event = SYSTEM_EVENT_MAX);
    // a lot more - skipped
};
```

Thus, there are actually three declarations of `onEvent()` with two parameters, thereby the 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter of each has a default argument. (Hence, the call `WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);` with only one argument in the example was OK.)

To puzzle this out completely, I looked for `WiFiEventCb`, `WiFiEventFuncCb`, and `WiFiEventSysCb` and found them in the same header file above of `class WiFiGenericClass`:

```
typedef void (*WiFiEventCb)(system_event_id_t event);
typedef std::function<void(system_event_id_t event, system_event_info_t info)> WiFiEventFuncCb;
typedef void (*WiFiEventSysCb)(system_event_t *event);
```

This is what the three `typedef`s mean:

1. `WiFiEventCb` ... a function pointer to a (free) function which returns `void` and has one parameter of type `system_event_id_t`
2. `WiFiEventFuncCb` ... a `std::function` object for anything returning `void` and having two parameters of types `system_event_id_t` and `system_event_info_t`
3. `WiFiEventSysCb` ... a function pointer to a (free) function which returns `void` and has one parameter of type `system_event_id_t*`.

Obviously, the example used the 2<sup>nd</sup> `onEvent()` as it is the only one accepting functions with two parameters.

Support of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is very nice, because it accepts anything callable with matching signature:

- free functions,
- functors,
- lambdas (which are actually nothing else than one of the former).

So, to make the `ApiClient::WiFiEvent()` compatible, there are two options:

1. declare `ApiClient::WiFiEvent()` as static member function
2. bind `ApiClient::WiFiEvent()` with an instance with which it is called.

The first option restricts the usability of `ApiClient::WiFiEvent()` as `static` member functions are called without an instance of the resp. class. The drawback – there is no instance in the member function available (i.e. explicit or implicit access to `this` prohibited) which may or may not be acceptable.

The second option can be achieved easily by using a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as adapter. For this, the event handler registration in `ApiClient::ApiClient()` has to be changed:

```
//ERROR: wifi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
//Instead:
wifi.onEvent(
  [this](WiFiEvent_t event, system_event_info_t info) {
    this->WiFiEvent(event, info);
  });
```

This effectively registers a functor with the accepted signature which captures `this` of `ApiClient` so that a valid call of member function with instance can be done. The return type of lambda is implicitly declared to `void` because there is no `return` in the body of the lambda.

Finally, I'd like to mention that capturing in lambdas is something which has to be done carefully. If `wifi` outlives `this` (i.e. the instance of `ApiClient`) then it may call `ApiClient::WiFiEvent()` without a valid `this`-pointer.

To make it "bullet-proof", the destructor of `ApiClient` could call `removeEvent()` using the `wifi_event_id_t` which is returned by `onEvent()`. (This should be stored in `ApiClient` for this purpose.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed, understandable explanation to a noob! :-)